# How to print always 4 digits on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm writing a javascript who is supposed to just print on a raw web-page and I'm finding some formatting problems.
I would like to know if there's a way to do something like printf("%4d",num) in Javascript, because I always need to print a number considering it with 4 digits.
It would be something like that:

Year

```
  1
```

Instead of:

Year

1

Comment: So you don't *really* mean "4 digits", you mean you want the numbers to consume 4 digits worth of space, right? A four-digit `1` would be `0001`.

Comment: `sprintf` is a function available in many languages, but explaining how to reimplement it in JavaScript is probably too broad for a Stackoverflow question. Of course, it sounds like something someone might have implemented already if you [searched for it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+sprintf&ia=qa).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: Pointly you're right, sorry for my english. I could also print 0001, it would be the same

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want all numbers to be 4 digits long, you need to prepend zeros until the number is 4 digits long.

```
function padNumber(number) {
    number = number.toString();

    while(number.length < 4) {
        number = "0" + number;
    }

    return number;
}
```

The conversion to string is necessary to make sure that:

- the `number` variable has a `length` property (numbers do not)
- the JS engine doesn't convert the return value to base form again (i.e. 0004 `->` 4)